# Required references in questions

Tags: support

I have some questions, and I'm new here.
I’d like to ask what references one would need to post here. Does it have to be peer reviewed journals?

Comment: Your question has been migrated here where you can get a clear answer by the moderators. AFAIK nobody checks references, all people interested in physics who can follow logic and mathematics are welcome to post on physics,se

Comment: The answer here depends on what exactly you mean by "references one would need to post here". Do you mean references for a topic you're *asking* about, references for an *answer* you're writing, or are you somehow under the impression we demand references for *yourself* to allow posting here at all?

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't already. please take [the tour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour).

> I’d like to ask what references one would need to post here.

The same qualifications required to become a cabinet minister of any country.  None at all.

You need no formal qualification or experience of physics at all.

That said you are expected to post questions you have made a reasonable attempt to find an answer to yourself and post answers that are properly researched and checked (not guesses or opinions).

If you mean references to documents or quotes then if you say 'I read in a book', we'd like to know the book. If you copy a picture from somewhere, we'd like to know from where. If you refer to a paper, we want a real reference to the paper.  Ideally references to academic papers should be links to the *abstract* page, not a direct PDF link.  Gives the authors and title and ideally a reference number so people have a reasonable chance of finding the document even if a link goes dead, as they often do.

> Does it have to be peer reviewed journals ?

The quality of your posts here are what counts.  There are definitely some current and retired full time physicists who are regulars, however there are many, many "amatuers" who contribute regularly as well.  It's how "professionally" you behave here that matters.

We will, in short, take anyone willing to make the effort to keep the standard of questions and answers high.  The community will tend to downvote bad questions and answers.

Comment: Well, if you say 'I read in a book', we'd like to know the book. If you copy a picture from somewhere, we'd like to know from where. If you refer to a paper, we want a real reference to the paper.